# Error: Call to a member function tasks() on null in file Http\Controllers\TaskController.php

Tags: laravel, jwt, relationship

I have configured `JWT` `laravel` and `postman`, I have two tables `users` and `tasks`, between them a relationship `hasMany` `BelongsTo` here:

**task.php**

```
public function user() {
         return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
     }
```

**User.php**

```
public function tasks()
     {
         return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
     }
```

and a function that returns list of `tasks`

**Taskcontroller.php**

```
public function index()
{
     $tasks = $this->user->tasks()->get(['title', 'description'])->toArray();

     return $tasks;
}
```

but it gives me error:

```
Error: Call to a member function tasks() on null in file C:\wamp64\www\jwtestb\app\Http\Controllers\TaskController.php on line 30
```

Comment: What is `$this->user`, where you get it from? Seems like it's null. If you want to use authenticated user, it's `Auth::user()`

Answer (score 0):

`$this->user` does not exist. If you want to get the authenticated user you can either use the `Auth` facade or the `Request` object.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; // or use Auth;

public function index()
{
     $tasks = Auth::user()->tasks()->get(['title', 'description'])->toArray();

     return $tasks;
}
```

```php
public function index()
{
     $tasks = auth()->user()->tasks()->get(['title', 'description'])->toArray();

     return $tasks;
}
```

```php
public function index()
{
     $tasks = request()->user()->tasks()->get(['title', 'description'])->toArray();

     return $tasks;
}
```

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index(Request $request)
{
     $tasks = $request->user()->tasks()->get(['title', 'description'])->toArray();

     return $tasks;
}
```